# Pattern Matching on lists behaving weird?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

While practicing scala, I am trying to insertion-sort an integer list using pattern matching. Previously, the following code for printing the list worked absolutely fine:

```
object PrintList {
 def iPrint(xs: List[Int]):Unit = xs match {

      case x :: ys => {
        print(x+" -> ")
        iPrint(ys)
      }
      case _ => println("Nil")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    //val l = Nil.::(1).::(2).::(3).::(4)
    val l = 4 :: 3 :: 2 :: 1 :: Nil

    iPrint(l)
  }
}
```

However, the following code to sort a list doesn't compile:

```
  def insert(x : Int, l1 : List[Int]):List = {
    //stubbed
    List()
  }

  def iSort(l : List[Int]):List = l match {

    case x :: ys => insert(x , iSort(ys))
    case Nil => Nil

  }
```

Am I missing something really trivial here??

**EDIT:**
Modified the code as below:

```
def insert(x : Int , l1 : List[Int]):List[Int] = {
    //stubbed
    List(0)
  }

  def iSort(l : List[Int]):List[Int] = l match {
    case (x:Int) :: (ys:List[Int]) => insert(x , iSort(ys))
    case _ => List(0)

  }
```

Still getting error in the first case statement - `Pattern type is incompatible with expected type. Found: ::[B], expected: List[Int]`

Using Intellij Idea with scala plugin - 2.11.7.

[image]

Comment: You may want to add compiler errors.
I don't get it. What parameters does `insert` take? Because it looks like it only takes one `List` parameter, but you're calling it with 2 paramters.

Comment: You might need to specify the type of your returned List: List[Int], plus your insert method takes only one parameter, not two.

Comment: as @hasumedic pointed out you also need to specify a type parameter for your returned `List`... something `List[Int]` so your function becomes `def iSort(l : List[Int]): List[Int]...`

Comment: I made a mistake in my initial question, the insert function takes two parameters: an integer and a list. Made the changes accordingly. However, I still get the same error. Tried all permutations mentioning the type parameters, still doesn't compile. Following is the error: `Pattern type is incompatible with expected type. found::[B], required List[Int]`. - even after adding type parameters to the List declarations and modifying the case statement to  `case (x:Int) :: (ys:List[Int]) => insert(iSort(ys))`. I am using intellij with scala plugin.

Comment: looks like a bug in intellij. try to execute the code in the scala repl

Comment: I've just compiled this in IntelliJ 15.0.2 without any errors.
My Scala version is 2.11.7

Comment: The code compiled fine on command line using scalac :) But I am using exactly the same IntelliJ and Scala versions - 15.0.2 and 2.11.7 respectively. What could the issue be with my IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r40qp.png), you are defining your own `List` class in that same package `Week04`. It's visible in your project browser on the left-hand side. So in your code

```
def iSort(l: List[Int]) = ???
```

you have an argument of type `Week04.List[Int]`. You try to destructure that using the `::` list-cons class. I presume you *have not* defined your version of `::`, least I don't remember that this was defined the Coursera class. So you have a `scala.::` here which is a sub-type of `scala.List`. So you are trying to pattern match against some completely different type. If you replaced every occurance of `List` with `scala.List` you would use Scala's standard list class instead and it should work. If you want that to work with your own list implementation, you need to define your own extractor.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that this solved the issue. I had my own version of `List[Int]` defined in the other file(List.scala). Thanks so much!! However, I am confused regarding the fact that scala doesn't import List from any package (like java.util). How does it decide which version of a class to use when there are multiple available?

Comment: And one more question out of curiosity.. Are you Martin Odersky yourself? :P

Comment: @AnkitKhettry Haha, no, just happen to have the same nationality :) And regarding the problem - no need to be embarrassed. Shadowing of names is a common source of mistakes in Scala, and the compiler could actually do better to hint at this.

Comment: Yeah well same Nationality and same initials and the same areas of strength. Too much co-incidence. You may choose to keep your 'air of mystery'. I'll boast of having been in a conversation with MARTIN ODERSKY to my friends xD And many thanks for the answer, too :) Really helped!